# EntityFramework and Model with fields of one class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, postgresql, ef-code-first

I have "User" and "Bid" models.

And ofcourse "Users" and "Bids" tables in DateBase. (["Bid" columns in postgres table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZLpX.png))

I can map one "User" field like this:

```cs
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

But have no idea how to map three "User" fields with different names.

```cs
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }//id of user in db table
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }//id of user in db table
    public int ExecutorId { get; set; }//id of user in db table
    public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
    public virtual User Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual User Executor { get; set; }
```

What should I do?

```cs
public class Bid
{
    public int BidId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateOfCreating { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfProcessing { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfExecution { get; set; }

    //here is something incorrect
    public int CreatorId { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    public int ExecutorId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
    public virtual User Manager { get; set; }
    public virtual User Executor { get; set; }

    public bool IsProcessed { get; set; }
    public bool IsExecuted { get; set; }
    public bool IsExecutionConfirmed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: not sure what your asking man! what do you want it to do?

Comment: Why is that incorrect?

Comment: Try to be more clear in what you're asking, and hopefully the negative sign next to your votes will go away.  If you're asking what I think you're asking, you should be able to specify this with fluent API in your OnModelCreating method in your context.

Comment: Poor language skills. I will study English more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you have to tell `Entity Framework` that the 3 properties should be used as foreign keys in the database.

Since they have unconventional names (EF wont recognize them as foreign keys automatically), you can help it understand by setting the `ForeignKey` attribute on them, and specifying which navigation properties they are foreign key values for.

```
[ForeignKey("Creator")]
public int CreatorId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Manager")]
public int ManagerId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("Executor")]
public int ExecutorId { get; set; }

public virtual User Creator { get; set; }
public virtual User Manager { get; set; }
public virtual User Executor { get; set; }
```

Comment: I found the solution at the same time when you answer. Yes, that exactly what I needed. Thank you.